# Usage of one go - 5 weeks in one go

Tags: word-usage

My friend told me that he had 5 weeks off from work. And I said "5 weeks in one go?" which I meant to ask that if it was without any break. How would a native say that? Is it ok to say "in one go" in this context or what could be the alternatives ?

Thanks

Comment: I would say either "a five-week vacation" to mean five consecutive weeks, or "five weeks of vacation" to indicate a total, without identifying whether they were consecutive or not.

Comment: Actually I'm curious about if the usage of "one go" is correct

Comment: Yes, five weeks at one go is correct.

Comment: I'm fine with *5 weeks in one go?*, but I might also say *5 weeks [all] **at once**?* sometimes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, you can say "in one go," as you did above, asking if he has taken all five weeks off at once.

Here's a definition of the set phrase:

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in/at%20one%20go

The definition says it is "chiefly British," which is true. But I think most Americans know the phrase, too.

I'm trying to think of other similar phrases:

> Five weeks in one go?
>
> All five weeks at once?

Just realize "in one go" is less formal, but people will understand what you mean. Plus, it's more fun to say.

As @Davo suggested, a "five-week vacation" is another clear way to say what you mean.

Comment: I added a link to a definition for the set phrase "in one go."